how to show that background process is running when page reloads
Environment:
APEX 23 and Oracle 21c under Windows 11.
I have a multi-page application.
One page(Say, Page1) launches a background execution chain, and I can see a spinning circle indicating that process is running.
From navigation menu I can switch to another page.
Now I want to see a spinning circle(if the process is still running), when I switch back to Page1.
How can I achieve this behavior?

There is no such a built-in functionality in Oracle Apex. However, I think you might implement a custom functionality using Ajax Callbacks and Page Load Dynamic Action.
The idea is that you should have a Run Id or a Unique Identifier for your process. You should store it in a application item whenever your page(Page 1) is submitted.
Then, since you have the run id of you execution chain stored in your item, whenever Page 1 is navigated, you can create a Page Load dynamic action that first checks if the process is finished as the server-side condition for given run id, if not finished, then it executes a Basic Javascript block such as:
var lSpinner$ = apex.util.showSpinner();

If you also have a logic where you store if the run is finished for the execution chain, you can then use lSpinner$.remove(); to remove the spinner.
